# ServiceStack OAuth2 mobile native authentication

Tags: servicestack

I need to log on through OAuth 2 how can I do that without using WebView in Android?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the latest [v4.5.7 of ServiceStack](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget) you'll be able to login into Twitter, Facebook or Github using their SDKs and [previous saved access tokens](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/AndroidJavaChat/blob/master/src/androidchat/app/src/main/java/servicestack/net/androidchat/App.java#L64).

Authentication via AccessToken is also [made available to OAuth2 providers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/70d7ca1daf88a56e502846e046903cf3c957704f) in the same way where you can authenticate directly by adding the AccessToken to the `Authenticate` Request DTO, e.g:

```
var request = new Authenticate
{
    provider = "GoogleOAuth",
    AccessToken = GoogleOAuthAccessToken,
};

var response = client.Post(request);
response.PrintDump();
```

Although you will first need to retrieve the AccessToken which typically requires opening a WebView to capture Users consent.

For other OAuth2 providers other than Google Auth you will need to provide an implementation of `VerifyAccessToken` that returns a boolean that determines whether the AccessToken is valid or not, e.g:

```
new MyOAuth2Provider {
    VerifyAccessToken = accessToken => MyValidate(ConsumerKey,accessToken),
}
```

This is different for each OAuth provider where some don't provide an API that lets you determine whether the AccessToken is valid with your App or not.

Comment: @myhtz oh I'm sorry ) I wanted to ask, when will the same opportunity via the standard SDK for other providers?

Comment: @MherArsh See updated answer for info on new support for direct AccessToken Auth in OAuth2 providers.